# Searched in the following locations:

Tags: android, firebase, build.gradle

Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.1.

Searched in the following locations:

```
file:/H:/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/15.0.1/firebase-core-15.0.1.pom
file:/H:/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/15.0.1/firebase-core-15.0.1.jar
file:/H:/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/15.0.1/firebase-core-15.0.1.pom
file:/H:/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/15.0.1/firebase-core-15.0.1.jar
file:/H:/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/15.0.1/firebase-core-15.0.1.pom
file:/H:/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/15.0.1/firebase-core-15.0.1.jar
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/15.0.1/firebase-core-15.0.1.pom
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/15.0.1/firebase-core-15.0.1.jar
https://maven.google.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/15.0.1/firebase-core-15.0.1.pom
https://maven.google.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/15.0.1/firebase-core-15.0.1.jar
```

Required by:
    project :app

I have checked build.gradle twice but can't find any solution. The library is not in the SDK directory (AndroidSDK), which the installation procedure insisted upon. I have installed the google repository using SDK Manager. In project setup I have the correct location of the SDK. How do I force AS to look in the correct directory?

**Build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 26
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.demo.xxxxx"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 26
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'

    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Root Level Gradle**

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
       // google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
       // google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: can you update your question with project level build.gradle?

Comment: The [Release Notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) show 15.0.2 is the current version of `firebase-core`.

Comment: I know 15.0.2 is current version of firebase-core but i never used firebase in my project

Comment: i have update my question with build.gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your root level Gradle to:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        // Other dependencies
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.1' // google-services plugin
    }
}
```

Also try adding this to your project level Gradle:

```
dependencies {
  // Other dependencies
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
}
```

If you're getting a 'Could not find...?' error, then try checking your root **build.gradle**.
If nothing gets you luck, try cleaning or rebuilding your project.